# VB6 TextBox_LostFocus() function doesnt get triggered when value is changed dynamically

Tags: vba, vb6

I am using WM_SETTEXT method of windows API in an application (say AppX coded in .NET) to set the text of a textbox in an application which is always running (say AppY coded in VB6). I am able to change the text dynamically.

However, when the textbox value gets updated, the TextBox_LostFocus() doesn't get fired. It does get fired if I go to App Y and manually type in some value into textbox and tab out (this works because of LostFocus event of VB6 getting triggered).

Is there anything  other than TextBox_LostFocus() in VB6 to achieve my requirement? Something that watches whether the textbox value ahs changed?

Comment: try your code with in TextBox_Change()

Comment: @sna2stha, can you answer to this question with the same reply so that I can mark it as answer..

Answer (score 0):

> However, when the textbox value gets updated, the TextBox_LostFocus() doesn't get fired.

That is because `WM_SETTEXT` only sets the data, it doesn't tab out and hence there is no `_LostFocus` event firing. You need to `Tab` out of the `TextBox`. For example

```
Const WM_IME_KEYDOWN = &H290
Const VK_TAB = &H9

SendMessage hWnd, WM_IME_KEYDOWN, VK_TAB, 0&
```